# Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains' Spring + Hibernate + UserDetailService

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-security

I just started to learn Spring Security and have some trouble. I want to configure User login on page with password and username which stored in database during registration. I use Hibernate.

My error stack:

```
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Mon Sep 30 16:16:07 EDT 2013]; root of context hierarchy
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/spring-context.xml]
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml]
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/security-context.xml]
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Overriding bean definition for bean 'guestBookDAOImpl': replacing [Generic bean: class [demidov.pkg.persistence.GuestBookDAOImpl]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/spring-context.xml]] with [Generic bean: class [demidov.pkg.persistence.GuestBookDAOImpl]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/security-context.xml]]
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@11dab12: defining beans [dataSource,sessionFactory,guestBookDAOImpl,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,transactionManager,org.springframework.security.filterChains,org.springframework.security.filterChainProxy,org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0,org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#1,org.springframework.security.web.PortMapperImpl#0,org.springframework.security.web.PortResolverImpl#0,org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0,org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository#0,org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionFixationProtectionStrategy#0,org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.HttpSessionRequestCache#0,org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased#0,org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0,org.springframework.security.web.access.DefaultWebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationProvider#0,org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint#0,org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0,org.springframework.security.userDetailsServiceFactory,org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#2,org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher#0,org.springframework.security.authenticationManager]; root of factory hierarchy
WARN : org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.DTDEntityResolver - HHH000223: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
WARN : org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.DTDEntityResolver - HHH000223: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
ERROR: org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate - HHH000388: Unsuccessful: create table USER_DESC (ID bigint not null auto_increment, USER_NAME varchar(255), USER_PASS varchar(255), USER_PRIV varchar(255) default ROLE_USER, USER_EMALE varchar(255), USER_GENDER varchar(255), primary key (ID))
ERROR: org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ROLE_USER, USER_EMALE varchar(255), USER_GENDER varchar(255), primary key (ID))' at line 1
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@11dab12: defining beans [dataSource,sessionFactory,guestBookDAOImpl,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,transactionManager,org.springframework.security.filterChains,org.springframework.security.filterChainProxy,org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0,org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#1,org.springframework.security.web.PortMapperImpl#0,org.springframework.security.web.PortResolverImpl#0,org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0,org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository#0,org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionFixationProtectionStrategy#0,org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.HttpSessionRequestCache#0,org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased#0,org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0,org.springframework.security.web.access.DefaultWebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationProvider#0,org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint#0,org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0,org.springframework.security.userDetailsServiceFactory,org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#2,org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher#0,org.springframework.security.authenticationManager]; root of factory hierarchy
ERROR: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#2' while setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [2]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#2': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0' while setting constructor argument with key [10]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported configuration attributes: [hasRole('ROLE_USER')]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:329)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:107)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:353)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:154)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1387)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1128)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:610)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5204)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5199)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#2': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0' while setting constructor argument with key [10]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported configuration attributes: [hasRole('ROLE_USER')]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:329)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:107)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:353)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:154)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:615)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:148)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1045)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:949)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:323)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported configuration attributes: [hasRole('ROLE_USER')]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:323)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported configuration attributes: [hasRole('ROLE_USER')]
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:156)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1541)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1479)
    ... 45 more
Sep 30, 2013 4:16:09 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#2' while setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [2]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#2': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0' while setting constructor argument with key [10]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported configuration attributes: [hasRole('ROLE_USER')]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:329)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:107)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:353)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:154)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1387)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1128)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:610)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5204)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5199)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#2': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0' while setting constructor argument with key [10]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported configuration attributes: [hasRole('ROLE_USER')]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:329)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:107)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:353)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:154)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:615)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:148)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1045)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:949)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:323)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported configuration attributes: [hasRole('ROLE_USER')]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:323)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported configuration attributes: [hasRole('ROLE_USER')]
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:156)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1541)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1479)
    ... 45 more
```

I can not get access any jsp pages after I add Spring Security.

My spring-context.xml

```
<security:http pattern="/guestbook" security="none" />
        <security:http pattern="/regestration" security="none" />

        <security:http auto-config="true">

            <security:intercept-url pattern="/user/*" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>

        </security:http>

        <security:authentication-manager>

            <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="guestBookDAOImpl"/>

        </security:authentication-manager>

        <bean id="guestBookDAOImpl" class="demidov.pkg.persistence.GuestBookDAOImpl"/>
```

My dao impl implemented with UserDetailsService from Spring Security:

```
@Transactional
public class GuestBookDAOImpl implements GuestBookDAOIF, UserDetailsService {


    public SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }


  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public  List<UserMessage> fetchAll() {
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("select userMessage from UserMessage userMessage").list();
}



    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public User fetchAllUsers(String userName) {

        return(User)sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("select user from User user where user.userName=:name")
                                                                                .setParameter("name", userName) .uniqueResult();
    }



    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userName)
                                    throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User user;

        Set<GrantedAuthority> userroles = new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>();

        User myuser = fetchAllUsers(userName);

        userroles.add(myuser);

        user = new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(myuser.getUserName(), myuser.getUserPassword(), true, true, true, true, userroles);

        return user;
    }
```

My User entity:

```
public class User implements Serializable, GrantedAuthority {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1576600424405883465L;


    private long userId;

    public long getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(long userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }


    private String userName;

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }


    private String userPassword;

    public String getUserPassword() {
        return userPassword;
    }

    public void setUserPassword(String userPassword) {
        this.userPassword = userPassword;
    }


    private String userRole;

    public String getUserRole() {
        return userRole;
    }

    public void setUserRole(String userRole) {
        this.userRole = userRole;
    }


    private String userEmale;

    public String getUserEmale() {
        return userEmale;
    }

    public void setUserEmale(String userEmale) {
        this.userEmale = userEmale;
    }


    private String userGender;

    public String getUserGender() {
        return userGender;
    }

    public void setUserGender(String userGender) {
        this.userGender = userGender;
    }


    private Set<UserMessage> userMessageList = new HashSet<UserMessage>();

    public Set<UserMessage> getUserMessageList() {
        return userMessageList;
    }

    public void setUserMessageList(Set<UserMessage> userMessageList) {
        this.userMessageList = userMessageList;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAuthority() {
        return getUserRole();
    }


}
```

Hibernate mapping xml fro user entity:

```
<hibernate-mapping>

        <class name="demidov.pkg.domain.User" table="USER_DESC">

            <!-- Primary key ID will be generated depends on database configuration -->
            <id name="userId" column="ID">
                <generator class="native"></generator>
            </id>

            <property name="userName" column="USER_NAME" unique="true" />

            <property name="userPassword" column="USER_PASS"/>

            <property name="userRole" >
                <column name="USER_PRIV" default="ROLE_USER"/> 
            </property>

            <property name="userEmale" column="USER_EMALE" unique="true"/>

            <property name="userGender" column="USER_GENDER" />


            <!-- User is owner of relationships, all changes on user will effect UserMessage entity -->
            <set name="userMessageList" inverse="true" lazy="false" fetch="select" cascade="all">

                <key>
                    <column name="USER_ID" not-null="true"/>
                </key>

                <one-to-many class="demidov.pkg.domain.UserMessage" />

            </set>

        </class>

    </hibernate-mapping>
```

Please help me. I'm confused what is what: GrantedAuthority, UserDetails, User and how they work with xml configuration of Spring Security.

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
 <security:http auto-config="true">
```

replace this section with the following:

```
 <security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
```

**Note:**

As a side note i see from the code and from comment i doubt you have injected SessionFactory from  GuestBookDAOImpl, thats causes NPE upon method call on the DAO layer. Inject it either from xml config or annotations.

Comment: Yes sir. It came up with another problem is: One of my methods from DAOImpl says SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [/web] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException at demidov.pkg.persistence.GuestBookDAOImpl.fetchAll(GuestBookDAOImpl.java:58). The method fetchAll() used to fetch all data from database and used them to render on jsp page.

Comment: Sir I did inject sessionFactory over annotation. What I remove everything of Spring Security it works but with Spring Security it don't.

Comment: What kind of problem are you facing, it would be better to add an update your question with additional information about the problem and explain what you did on the code. My answer only solved your problem with the expressions on the spring configuration.

Answer (score 16):

Bean creation error for "org.springframework.security.filterChains" comes when you are using spring version higher than 3.1 and have not added dependencies manually for spring-aop, spring-jdbc, spring-tx and spring-expressions in you POM.xml.

Reason : If don't do so, maven automatically downloads older version jars (3.0.x) for these artifacts which conflict with newer version spring security jars.

Answer (score 1):

use  `use-expressions="true"` along with   `auto-config="true"`

```
<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">       
       <security:intercept-url pattern="/user/*" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/> </security:http>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.