# Spring Autowired Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, authentication, spring-security, nullpointerexception, autowired

I'm having some problems developing a very simple web application using Spring-MVC (4.2.5), Spring-Security (4.0.3) and MongoDB.

I'm trying to implement a custom authentication provider, in order to login the user via database, using DAO pattern. Although it seems to have initialized properly the application context, I'm having Null Pointer Exception on the Autowired variables (CustomerDao and CustomUserDetailsService).

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
    <display-name>AcmeSpring</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SpringController</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-mvc.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SpringController</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**spring-mvc.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.5.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="controller" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="model" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="dao" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="service" />

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <bean id="templateResolver"
        class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/html/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
        <property name="templateMode" value="HTML5" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="templateEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine">
        <property name="templateResolver" ref="templateResolver" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
        <property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine" />
        <property name="order" value="1" />
    </bean>

    <mongo:db-factory id="mongoDbFactory" host="localhost"
        port="27017" dbname="AcmeSpring" />

    <bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
        <constructor-arg ref="mongoDbFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="customerDao" class="dao.CustomerDaoImpl">
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**spring-security.xml**

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd">

    <http pattern="/resources/**" security="none" />

    <http auto-config="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/user/**" access="hasRole('USER')" />
        <form-login authentication-failure-url="/login" login-page="/login"
            login-processing-url="/login" default-target-url="/user" />
        <logout invalidate-session="true" success-handler-ref="logoutSuccessHandler" />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider ref="customAuthenticationProvider" />
    </authentication-manager>

    <beans:bean id="customUserDetailsService" class="service.CustomUserDetailsService">
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="customAuthenticationProvider" class="service.CustomAuthenticationProvider">
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="logoutSuccessHandler" class="service.CustomLogoutSuccessHandler">
    </beans:bean>
</beans:beans>
```

**CustomAuthenticationProvider**

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {
    @Autowired
    CustomUserDetailsService userDetails;

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        String username = authentication.getName();
        String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

        System.out.println(userDetails == null);

        Customer customer = userDetails.loadUserByUsername(username);

        if(customer == null) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Username errato");
        }

        if(!password.equals(customer.getPassword())) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Password errata");
        }

        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(customer.getRole()));

        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(customer, password, authorities);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return clazz.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
    }
}
```

**CustomUserDetailsService**

```
@Service
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
    @Autowired
    private CustomerDao customerDao;

    @Override
    public Customer loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        return customerDao.findCustomerByUsername(username);
    }
}
```

**CustomerDaoImpl**

```
@Repository
public class CustomerDaoImpl implements CustomerDao {
    private static final String COLLECTION = "Customer";
    @Autowired
    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    @Override
    public void create(Customer customer) {
        this.mongoTemplate.insert(customer, COLLECTION);
    }

    @Override
    public Customer findCustomerByUsername(String username) {
        Query query = new Query();
        query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("username").is(username));
        System.out.println(query.toString());
        return this.mongoTemplate.findOne(query, Customer.class);
    }
}
```

**stack trace**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    service.CustomUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(CustomUserDetailsService.java:18)
    service.CustomAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(CustomAuthenticationProvider.java:32)
    org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:167)
    org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:192)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:93)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:217)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:120)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
```

Where am I wrong?
Thank you in advance.

EDIT: I don't have initialized the autowired variable manually, just bad paste, I've edited my code.

EDIT2: as suggested by @iMysak I remove the customerDao bean declaration from spring-mvc.xml and the 3 services bean declaration from spring-security.xml

**new stack trace**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#1' while setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [1]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#1': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#5adbfd3' of type [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter] while setting constructor argument with key [4]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#5adbfd3': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'logoutSuccessHandler' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'logoutSuccessHandler' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:382)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:157)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1481)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:753)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4853)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5314)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#1': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#5adbfd3' of type [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter] while setting constructor argument with key [4]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#5adbfd3': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'logoutSuccessHandler' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'logoutSuccessHandler' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:313)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:129)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:382)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:157)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:634)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:140)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1143)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1046)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#5adbfd3': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'logoutSuccessHandler' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'logoutSuccessHandler' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:634)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:140)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1143)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1046)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:299)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'logoutSuccessHandler' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:698)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1175)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:284)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
    ... 48 more
```

I also tried adding aop, tx and expressions dependencies as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19099289/error-creating-bean-with-name-org-springframework-security-filterchains-spring) but I get the above stack trace

Comment: Try to add this line in spring-security.xml :  <bean id="customerDao" class="dao.CustomerDaoImpl"></bean>

Comment: Yes, both CustomerDao (interface) and CustomerDaoImpl are in dao package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be problem with using multiple `context:component-scan` tags. Please try next:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="controller model dao service" />
```

instead of declaration them separately.

Comment: same error even changing the component-scan as you suggested

Comment: @andy can you move out  these missed bean's declarations from **spring-security.xml** and put into **spring-mvc.xml**  ?  customUserDetailsService and fea others. just to ensure

Comment: I tried, but I get a "Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains'"

Comment: in case of using defining **dao** and **service** under _context:component-scan_ you shouldn't even declare them in xml so you can even remove them from xml. What exactly error did you get with filterChains ?

Comment: please look on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19099289/error-creating-bean-with-name-org-springframework-security-filterchains-spring also

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135638/discussion-between-imysak-and-andy).

Comment: Fixed: in the end I used component-scan and annotation to inject beans as suggested and modify my web.xml as suggested [here](http://javainsimpleway.com/spring-security-using-custom-login-form/). Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You made the classic Spring bean mistake.  You annotated the bean:

```
@Autowired
CustomUserDetailsService userDetails;
```

You called new:

```
userDetails = new CustomUserDetailsService();
```

It's either under Spring control or yours.  The moment you called new, it was out of Spring's hands.

If you want Spring to auto wire dependencies, you cannot call new to initialize the reference.  Let Spring do it.

Comment: I don't really have userDetails = new CustomUserDetailsService() in my code, sorry for the bad paste: I tried to delete all Autowired annotation and to initialize manually the dao and the service, going back I forgot to delete that row. I know that I don't have to initialize the variables if these are autowired. I've edited my question

Answer (score 0):

Can you try getting rid of

```
<beans:bean id="customAuthenticationProvider" class="service.CustomAuthenticationProvider">
</beans:bean>
```

and

```
<beans:bean id="customUserDetailsService" class="service.CustomUserDetailsService">
    </beans:bean>
```

I think the XML declaration might be redundant with the annotation declaration and component scan

Comment: removing these rows I get an "Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains' " etc.